# Why file's name get messy using archive/zip in golang, linux?

Tags: linux, character-encoding, go, zip

I'm using golang's standard package archive/zip to wrap several files into a zipfile.
Here is my code for test:

```
package main

import (    
    "archive/zip"
    "log"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    archive, _ := os.Create("/tmp/测试file.zip")
    w := zip.NewWriter(archive)

    // Add some files to the archive.
    var files = []struct {
        Name, Body string
    }{
        {"测试.txt", "test content: 测试"},
        {"test.txt", "test content: test"},
    }

    for _, file := range files {
        f, err := w.Create(file.Name)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }

        _, err = f.Write([]byte(file.Body))
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
    }

    err := w.Close()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

results:
I get a zip file named `测试file.zip` under `/tmp` as expected.
After `unzip` it, I get two files: `test.txt`, `ц╡ЛшпХ.txt`, and that is a mess.
The contents in both of the two files are normal as expected.

Why does this happen and how to fix this?

Comment: I believe this might be related to the different ecodings Windows and Linux use for their file names. On which operating system did you generate `测试file.zip`?

Comment: @FUZxxl It's ubuntu.

Comment: You could try to run the filename through https://godoc.org/code.google.com/p/go-charset/charset

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be an [issue with `unzip`](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unzip/+bug/580961) not handling UTF8 names properly. Explicitly using the Chinese locale worked for me:

```
$ LANG=zh_ZH unzip 测试file.zip
Archive:  测试file.zip
  inflating: 测试.txt              
  inflating: test.txt
$ cat *.txt
test content: testtest content: 测试
```

Comment: Pretty cool! I've also tried unzip it on windows using a tool named `WinRAR`, the results are messy as well. So, can I consider `WinRAR` not handling UTF-8 names properly either? More details of the mechanism through the whole test process would be extremely helpful. :)

Comment: @H.W.Du WinRAR might have the same problems, I can't say for sure without a Windows machine. Not sure what you mean by "more details".

Comment: I mean, by the phemomenon that, the zipfile's name and the inflated files' content are all as expected, only inflated file's name are a mess, what's the reason inside?

Comment: @H.W.Du I have no idea, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

```
import {
    "golang.org/x/text/encoding/simplifiedchinese"
    "golang.org/x/text/transform"
}

filename, _, err = transform.String(simplifiedchinese.GBK.NewEncoder(), "测试.txt")
```